# How do I able to change custom setting values from test class to actual class

Tags: trigger, unit-test, customsetting

I found a problem that couldn't change custom setting values through test code

To prevent recursive call, in the middle of context put switch code like below
(trigger only runs when custom setting instance value is true)

```
 Trigger__c.getInstance('AfterTrigger').Active__c =false
 update tempList;
 Trigger__c.getInstance('AfterTrigger').Active__c =true;
```

Declared custom setting in Test code as well.

```
 List<Trigger__c> cs = new List<Trigger__c>();
 cs.add(new Trigger__c(Name= 'AfterTrigger',Active__c=true));
 insert cs;
```

The problem is test code able to access custom setting but not able to change their values in actual code. it still remains as true.

Is there any good way to resolve this problem? (hope not to use `seealldata`)

Comment: Custom Settings persisted in test context are present throughout the scope of the unit test run (`@testSetup` execution plus `@isTest` method execution). They don't persist beyond that scope and "real" Custom Settings instances aren't visible inside the test context. I'm having a hard time following what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually update (perform DML upon) the setting for it to take effect:

```
Trigger__c value = Trigger__c.getInstance('AfterTrigger');
value.Active__c = false;
update value;
update tempList;
value.Active__c = true;
update value;
```

In general, though, this is a Bad Idea. The setting will lock up all other triggers that use it for the duration of the execution. It definitely should not be updated in a trigger context. Instead, use a static variable to control recursion, or design a pattern that checks only on "rising edge" conditions (e.g. the record did not meet a condition but does now).

It's okay to use a custom setting for persistent control of the trigger, however.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I rather used oldmap to check if there are any changes for preventing recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Our approach to this issue is to have a class through which we access a related static boolean value, e.g. TriggerUtils.SKIP_TRIGGER_FOR_ACCOUNT. This boolean can be written to by production and/or test code to disable trigger processing and the trigger itself simply wraps all processing inside an if block that is conditional on (for example) !TriggerUtils.SKIP_TRIGGER_FOR_ACCOUNT.